# Can not login Dashboard / Unable to find the server at mykeystoneurl

Tags: openstack

I installed Dashboard following this guide:
http://wiki.openstack.org/OpenStackDashboard

Everything fine, but when I run the server, I can not login with the username and password in DATABASE config in local_settings.py. Here's my config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dashboarddb',
        'USER': 'nova',
        'PASSWORD': 'nova',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'default-character-set': 'utf8'
    },
}
```

When I run the Dashboard server and enter username + password. It returned this error on browser:
Unable to find the server at mykeystoneurl (HTTP 400)

And in the command line:

```
DEBUG:openstack_dashboard.settings:Running in debug mode without debug_toolbar.
DEBUG:openstack_dashboard.settings:Running in debug mode without debug_toolbar.
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3.1, using settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:8888/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Request returned failure status.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/us/horizon/.venv/src/python-keystoneclient/keystoneclient/client.py",   line 121, in request
body = json.loads(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
[06/Mar/2012 15:20:03] "POST /auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3735
```

I also tried login as "**admin**" with password is "**password**" or "**secrete**" but I didn't work.
What's wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running a keystone server, and point the dashboard toward it via the `OPENSTACK_HOST` settings in `local_settings.py`

Answer (score 0):

Yes,the dashboard must run on the PC with keystone runnig on it.And you must point the dashboard toward it via the OPENSTACK_HOST ,and also the CACHE_BACKEND must aloso point to the keystone server's url